# Set Android View to Invisible/Gone Not Working

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

I have a surfaceview for which im putting a camera preview onto.  On top of that, I have a relative layout that has a bunch of views, like a scan button, etc.

I am trying to make one of these views invisible, like this

```
myIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

And I have also tried

```
myIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Neither seems to be working.  Invisible doesn't work at all, and Gone *sort of works*

Here you can see a 2D icon, a settings button.  Before hiding, it looks like this:

[image: inital]

Then I call setVisibility(View.GONE)

[image]

You can clearly see that the linearlayout that holds those views responded by giving the settings button more space, but it didnt remove the 2D from behind it.  I think it has something to do with the SurfaceView, because I know this would normally work.

I have tried

```
myIcon.requestFocus();
```

After I do the change of visibility, but still nothing.

Any suggestions? Please only respond if you have some experience with this particular problem

Edit:
Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.sample.SampleJavaCameraView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/cv_surface_view" />






<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    

  
  
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/myIcon"
    android:layout_width="30dip"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:src="@drawable/twod_icon"
    
    />

    <ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/settingsBtn"
    android:layout_width="30dip"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:src="@drawable/settings_gear"
    android:background="@null"
    />
</LinearLayout>


  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/scan_btn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/logo_small"
      android:background="@drawable/blue_radial_grad"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:padding="20dip"
       />
```

Here you can see the images im trying to hide are wrapped in a linear layout.  The surfaceview is at the top, it is the OpenCV wrapped class for a SurfaceView

Comment: Please post the relevant XML layout and/or Java code, I see what is happening in the picture but it's impossible to guess why with out more detail.

Comment: Please post some part of code and xml

Comment: Ok I posted the layout.  My activity is huge, and because of the OpenCV wrapped SurfaceView stuff, there is not much other java code that is relevant

Comment: Have you tried `myIcon.requestLayout();`?

Comment: Yes, tried to do it before and after setting the visibility, nothing working yet.  I found another posting saying basically, the view doesnt get the hint to change, and sometimes requesting focus can snap it back.  no luck yet

Answer (score 2):

maybe try `myIcon.bringToFront();`